# Changing Vega visualisation data source in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I'm a newbie to Kibana and Vega charts, I've found the perfect Vega chart:

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/edge-bundling

I've started to create this using the custom visualisation inside of Kibana but the example points to a URL as its data source.

As Kibana can only display data stored in ES, how do I change the data source to a CSV / JSON file I've uploaded?